# How to reconcile columns in sepearte ws, and return missing lines in a third ws?

Tags: excel, vba

Evening,

I am attempting to compare data from column “A” (starting rom row 2) of ws “Consolidated” to column “D” (starting from row 17) of ws “OTL”.  For each mismatch, a new line should be created in a third worksheet called “Reconciliation” (Ideally the whole line would be copied but I would be happy with just the number)

This is what I have to date:

```
Sub Differentiation()

Set RECsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Reconciliation")
Set OTLsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("OTL")
Set CONsheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Consolidation")

lrREC = RECsheet.Cells(Sheets("RECsheet").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lrOTL = ORLsheet.Cells(Sheets("OTLsheet").Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row
lrCON = CONsheet.Cells(Sheets("CONsheet").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lrCON
foundTrue = False
For j = 17 To lrOTL

If Sheets("CONSheet").Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets("OTLsheet").Cells(j, 4).Value Then
    foundTrue = True
    Exit For
End If

Next j

If Not foundTrue Then
    Sheets("CONSheet").Rows(i).Copy Destination:= _
    Sheets("Consolidation").Rows(lrREC+ 1)
    lrREC = lrREC + 1

End If

Next i

'stop screen from updating to speed things up
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

I know this probably looks like a dog's breakfast to you but I did try very hard (on this for 14 hours!!! haha)

Would love your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'd split up this into two sections. First, find mismatches: Do this simply with something like `iferror(vlookup(ThingToLookup,TableInOtherWS,1,0),"MISMATCH")`. Copy this down in your full range. This will give you a list of mismatches. Then do something like (I'm not testing this, but you should get my point)

```
'start in the WS with the MISMATCH column, with the first range of that column selected

dim arr(10000,2) 'assuming you want to copy over 3 fields... increase for more fields... and assuming 10000 rows
i=0
while activecell.value <>""
    if activecell.value ="MISMATCH" then
        arr(i,0)=activecell.offset(0,-4).value 'change -4 to whatever u wanna copy
        arr(i,1)=activecell.offset(0,-3).value 
        arr(i,2)=activecell.offset(0,-2).value 
    end if
    i=i+1
    activecell.offset(1,0).activate
wend

'now dump out results in a new book
worksheet.add
for i_ctr  = 0 to i
    activecell.offset(i_ctr ,0).value= arr(i_ctr,0)
    activecell.offset(i_ctr ,1).value= arr(i_ctr,1)
    activecell.offset(i_ctr ,2).value= arr(i_ctr,2)
next
```

run it slowly by pushing F8 line by line to see how it proceeds. Good luck!

Comment: Hey - that does not work and I am not sufficiently knowledgeable to fix it : (